# Apache Virtual Host Wordpress Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I successfully created an Apache Virtual Host on my dedi for Subdomains, which works good. The only problem is, that Wordpress creates sub-pages like this: `name.tld/page/`

How can I say apache that this is an under page from wordpress instead of sub-folder, because `http://flamespersecond.de/home/` works but any under page from this wordpress page doesn't works?

> "Not Found
>
> The requested URL /home/neuigkeiten/ was not found on this server."

My Virtual Host file looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost IP:80
<VirtualHost IP:80>
    ServerAdmin EMAIL
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/flamespersecond
    ServerName flamespersecond.de/
    ServerAlias flamespersecond.de/
    ErrorLog /home/vweb1/log/flamespersecond-error.log
    CustomLog /home/vweb1/log/flamespersecond-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what is your wordpress permalink setting ?

Comment: The Setting is: "Post name - http://flamespersecond.de/home/sample-post/"

Answer (score 0):

I have switched the host, now is everything fine! Thanks anyway.